# Is it possible to load BCP file to memory in C# with some library class?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, bcp

I have a BCP file that have data errors in some records. I need to load it up, fix problems and write it out back where it was. Is it possible using .NET mechanisms? By all means I can create structures and read it as a text file but I was wondering if I really have to do all this churning instead of relying on some cool .NET class.

Comment: *...wondering if I really have to do all this churning instead of relying on some cool .NET class...* [Write a cool .NET class that implements this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718897(v=sql.105).aspx) then you can do both!

Comment: @ta.speot.is I guess :)

Comment: If your BCP file is CSV, then you can likely use CSV libraries.